# Randomly choosing text with Javascript and displaying it

Tags: javascript

I'm having one of those days where I can't put into words what I'm trying to find. So, forgive me if this question has been asked before, if it has, I simply cannot find it.

If I have ten different lots of text, how can I randomly select one of them with Javascript, and display it.

The closest I've got is this:

```js
var textArray = [
  'Hello Fred',
  'Hello Jimmy',
  'Hello Terry'
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);

audioElement.setAttribute('src', textArray[randomNumber]);
```

```html
<p id="text-here">This is where I want the text to go</p>
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't close to what I need though.

Comment: (1) You need to escape the `'` characters in your strings, or enclose the strings in `"` instead of `'`. (2) If you're dealing with text strings for display, why are you setting the `src` attribute of an audio element!?

Comment: This was an answer found on a similar-ish StackOverflow question. I didn't want to seem like I haven't looked around. This is just the closest example I've found to my requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested it and it works just fine. Just enclose your array string values in double quotes and everything will work as you expected.

Here it is just setting the `innerHTML` value of **p** tag which is selected by `id` **randomNumber** and then set it with random text value of your array.

**getElementById:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

**innerHTML:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

```js
var textArray = [
  "Hello I'm Fred1",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy1",
  "Hello I'm Terry1",
  "Hello I'm Fred2",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy2",
  "Hello I'm Terry2",
  "Hello I'm Fred3",
  "Hello I'm Jimmy3",
  "Hello I'm Terry3"
];
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * textArray.length);
document.getElementById("randomNumber").innerHTML = textArray[randomNumber];
```

```html
<p id="randomNumber"> </p>
```

Comment: Then with html, `<p id="randomNumber"> </p>`?  (Sorry, very new to JS)

Comment: @MattH see my edit now.If you run the added example snippet that I posted here you will see that it is just setting the innerHTML value of  **<p>** tag based on the random text value of array.

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to create random number

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

Call the function to get a random number which will act as the array index

```
var index = getRandomInt(9)
```

Now considering you have array as 'textArray' then you can write

```
var text = textArray[index]
```

Now to update the value in paragraph

```
document.getElementById("text-here").innerHTML=text;
```